# Working with databases with Python: Course registration data in JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I am able to get my Python code to run print the desired results, but my problem is with the SQLite table.  I was asked to apply this SQL command to the tables:

```
SELECT hex(User.name || Course.title || Member.role ) AS X
    FROM User JOIN Member JOIN Course 
    ON User.id = Member.user_id AND Member.course_id = Course.id
    ORDER BY X
```

I was able to execute the command in SQLite, but according to the instructions for this project, X is supposed to start with 416 in row one of the results column produced.  However, the X I got for row 1 in the results was:

43616C6962736933313030

Here is what I wrote in Python so far:

```
import sqlite3
import json

#Working with Java and Sqlite

conn = sqlite3.connect('rosterdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Course;

CREATE TABLE User(
 id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
 name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Member(
user_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
course_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
    role INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, course_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Course(
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
title TEXT UNIQUE
);
''') 

#primary key for junction table is composite of both user_id and course_id

fname = raw_input("Enter file name:")
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'roster_data.json'

#prompts for file name

str_data = open(fname).read()
json_data = json.loads(str_data)

#opens the file and reads it all
#loads the json data and now is a python list
for entry in json_data:
    title = entry[1];
    name = entry [0];
    role = entry[2];
    #["Charley, "sill0", 1] represents the name, course title, and role

    print name, title, role

    cur.execute('''INSERT or IGNORE INTO User (name)
        VALUES (?)''', (name, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ?',(name, ))
    user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT or IGNORE INTO Course (title)
        VALUES (?)''', (title, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Course WHERE title = ?', (title, ))
    course_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT or REPLACE INTO Member (user_id, course_id, role)
        VALUES (?,?,?)''', (user_id, course_id, role))

#INSERT, SELECT AND FETCHONE STATEMENTS
    conn.commit()
```

Here is the JSON data that I was working with.  It is about course registration for students: roster_data.json  Here is the link to it:

https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/sql-intro/roster_data.php?PHPSESSID=9addd537cfe55c03585d2bfaa757f6b0

I am not sure if I implemented the "role" key correctly.  Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: Cannot open the given link

Comment: We are not running LTI so we cannot access your linked data. You may need to consider another method to share that (or possibly some useful subset?).

Comment: I am not sure how to attach a file to this website.  If anyone can suggest something, please let me know.  I have actually been curious about this.

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ddf8284df20558d86507e7468d3c14ce

Comment: I used an online editor for JSON, and it said that I would be able to share the file openly.

Comment: Hello @cybernerd, why are user_id and course_id UNIQUE in the member table? If I understand correctly a user can appear many times, each time with a different course. As a pair (user_id, course_id) are unique - this is satisfied by making them primary key. This is one cause for your problem. Hope it fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Also @cybernerd, I see you made the name of user UNIQUE (in user table). This means you cannot have two people with the same name. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Hi @TalJ.Levy  Thank you for this.  I almost forgot that that composite primary key already sets it up to be unique as a pair.~  I overlooked the idea of many-to-many relationships for databases.~

Comment: Hmmm.  I think this project is asking for no repetition.  I will try both situations when I run the code and see where the expected output matches.

Comment: It worked without changing the UNIQUE in user table and also worked with the change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you made `Member.course_id` unique. Thus you can have no more members than courses. Using `REPLACE` in `INSERT or REPLACE into Member` hides this error.

Just drop `UNIQUE` constraint on `Member.course` and you will get expected result.

Comment: I believe that also Member.user_id cannot be unique.  Because a user can appear more then once.

Comment: Agree, it seems natural for a user to be a member of several courses.

Comment: Yes, I agree also.  Thank you again~